# How to disabled X-Spam header rewrite in WHM?

Tags: exim, spamassassin, cpanel, whm

I need some help with the settings on my cpanel WHM. I want to disable the options to stop rewriting the X-Spam in the header. When I send the spam emails for a test, I'm getting this:

```
X-Spam-Subject:   Hey
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=904.8
X-Spam-Score: 9048
X-Spam-Bar: +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
X-Spam-Report: Spam detection software, running on the system "server.mydomain.com",
has identified this incoming email as possible spam.  The original
message has been attached to this so you can view it or label
similar future email.  If you have any questions, see
root\@localhost for details.
Content preview:  XJS*C4JDBQADN1.NSBN3*2IDNEN*GTUBE-STANDARD-ANTI-UBE-TEST-EMAIL*C.34X
    XJS*C4JDBQADN1.NSBN3*2IDNEN*GTUBE-STANDARD-ANTI-UBE-TEST-EMAIL*C.34X
Content analysis details:   (904.8 points, 5.0 required)
  pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
1000 GTUBE                  BODY: Generic Test for Unsolicited Bulk Email
  0.0 URIBL_BLOCKED          ADMINISTRATOR NOTICE: The query to URIBL was
                             blocked.  See
                             DnsBlocklists - SPAMASSASSIN - Apache Software Foundation
                              for more information.
                             [URIs: my-email-signature.link]
-0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
  0.0 FREEMAIL_FROM          Sender email is commonly abused enduser mail
                             provider
                             [email[at]xxxxxxx.com]
-0.0 SUBJECT_IN_WELCOMELIST Subject: contains string in the user's
                             welcome-list
  0.2 FREEMAIL_ENVFROM_END_DIGIT Envelope-from freemail username ends
                             in digit
                             [email[at]xxxxxxx.com]
  1.2 HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_02    BODY: HTML has a low ratio of text to image
                             area
  0.3 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_04     BODY: HTML: images with 0-400 bytes of words
  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_AU          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
                             author's domain
  0.1 DKIM_SIGNED            Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily
                             valid
-0.1 DKIM_VALID             Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature
-0.1 DKIM_VALID_EF          Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from
                             envelope-from domain
  2.0 PYZOR_CHECK            Listed in Pyzor
                             (Welcome to Pyzor’s documentation! — Pyzor 1.0 documentation)
  0.0 TVD_SPACE_RATIO        No description available.
-100 SUBJECT_IN_WHITELIST   DEPRECATED: See SUBJECT_IN_WELCOMELIST
  1.2 T_REMOTE_IMAGE         Message contains an external image
X-Spam-Flag: YES
```

I have looking at the options in the WHM > Exim Configuration Manager >

Apache SpamAssassin™: X-Spam-Subject/Subject header prefix for spam emails [?]

I have disabled it but it does nothing. It will still rewrite the X-Spam in the header when the emails have been monitoring by **spamassassin** and move to junk folder.

I don't know what options I need to look on in the WHM to configure it

Do you know what options I need to look at in the Exim Configuration Manager to stop the spamassassian from rewriting X-Spam in the header when the emails have been pick up as spam and move to junk folder??

Comment: any idea???????????????????

Comment: @Rohit Gupta Do you have any idea??????